# Visual Studio closes my application while debugging and trying to watch some variable

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, watch

I am trying to debug my application in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. There are certain variables that when I am trying to watch hovering my cursor over them start to show their usual drop down info but before any useful information displayed my application exits. No crashes or something just like when I hit Stop debugging. Any idea? Again, my application is paused so nothing is happening at the time. It's a tree structure I made so maybe I am creating and "endless tree" by settint a node's parent variable to itself? And the debugger is trying to explore all member variables, and member variable of those member variables and so on when showing info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio evaluates each property when you hover your cursor over a variable while debugging. I had a property that was not properly coded and threw an exception